# Interaction between Messiah (role) and Ankh of Reincarnation (item)?

Tags: werewolv.es

If a Messiah holds an Ankh of Reincarnation and uses their ability (Sacrifice), does the Messiah return after 3 days, as expected from the ability, or after one day, as expected from the Ankh of Reincarnation? In other words: does the Messiah always automatically use up the Ankh if they use their Sacrifice ability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ankh will trigger the night after the Messiah's death, whether the Messiah triggers their ability themselves or is killed by other means.